# I have an error while making a request (403 Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request

I'm trying to load the main page of crunhyroll.com. And I get an error:

> (403 Forbidden)

I've set my user-agent and still get this error.

```
const request = require('request')

const options = {
    headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}
}

request('https://www.crunchyroll.com/', options ,(err,res,body)=> {
        console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```